# Implementing a custom command in a basic shell(in C)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, operating-system, system-calls

I need to implement a custom command in a shell .The goal is to support a command `program_name m` that creates a child process to execute `program_name`, but aborts the process if it does not complete its operation in m seconds.

Actually I am checking the status of waitpid(child_pid,&exit_status,WUNTRACED) everytime ,but the code segment in the for loop is not working and is not aborting the process!!
Can anyone suggest me an appropriate routine from the library to deliver a SIGALRM signal after m seconds, and use a signal handler to perform appropriate actions?
Thanks in advance!!

```
int child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid < 0) {
        perror("ERROR: could not fork process.\n");
    }
    if (child_pid == 0) {
        char *args[4];
        args[0] = path;
        args[1] = "-c";
        args[2] = command_line;
        args[3] = (char *) 0;

        //executing the command
        int exec_return = execvp(path, args);

        if (exec_return == -1) {
            perror("error: command execution failed!\n");
        } else {
            exit(exec_return);
        }
    } else {
        //assigning cur_fg_pid to the child
        cur_fg_pid = child_pid + 1;
        if (cur_fg_cmd == NULL) { cur_fg_cmd = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)); }
        strcpy(cur_fg_cmd, command_line);
        int exit_status;
        while (can_wait == 1 && waitpid(child_pid, &exit_status, 0) > 0) {}            
        cur_fg_pid = -1;
        cur_fg_cmd = NULL;
        if (can_wait == 1) latest_jobid = -1;

        if(global_time_flag)
    {
    for (i = 0; i < stip_time; i++) {
         if (waitpid(child_pid,&exit_status,WUNTRACED) > 0)
                if (WIFSTOPPED(exit_status)) {
                        break;
             } else {sleep(1);}

        }
            if(!WIFSTOPPED(exit_status ))
             kill (child_pid, SIGUSR1);
    }
        }
```

Comment: Have you considered just using the `timeout` command instead of trying to write your own?  Failing that, try calling `alarm()` see `man 2 alarm`

Comment: Note that there is no need to check the value returned by execvp.  If it returns, then it failed.  (Not that there's anything wrong with checking it, and might be useful to allow execvp to be replaced in the future with a wrapper)

Comment: Using timeout will not help since I need to display proper messages once the process is aborted. Can you please help me regarding using alarm() to implement the above ?

Comment: @BibhasRanjanDas: But `timeout` will return a distinctive exit code `124` on timeout, you can use it.

Comment: @rodrigo My bad!! thanks a bunch !! But I would really like someone to help me implement my own instead of using timeout !!

Comment: Hello, this is a community forum, and you should appreciate any help or suggestions. Why not you learn gnu coreutils, you can get the source and see if you can solve the problem. Gnu coreutils, an open source project, timeout is part of it. Check the source and it will help